# Where can I ask questions regarding what library I should I use?

Tags: support

I have an app I would like to implement, but I'm not sure where can I ask what tools should I use. I know Stack Overflow, but in the rules it is not allowed to ask about what technologies to use.

Can anyone tell me if there´s an appropriate SE site to ask this kind of question?